# Create dataframes based on differences in a column by a conditional variable

Tags: r

I have **df1**:

```
ID  Name  Score  Category
100 AA    1: M   1
100 BB    2: M   1
200 CC    3: M   1
200 DD    2: M   2
300 EE    4: L   1
300 FF    NA     1
400 GG    1: M   3
400 HH    1: M   3
```

I need 2 output dfs - **df2** containing only rows where the 'Score' Differs WITHIN a 'Category' per ID (as in ID 100 & 300) and **df3** with rows only where the 'Score' differs BETWEEN a 'Category' per ID (as in ID 200.

I include an NA as in this case, an NA would also be considered as a score, meaning ID 300 contains a WITHIN difference.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Score is currently a factor - it does contain values & characters

Comment: 1: M and 2: M would be different as above, ID 100 contains a difference WITHIN same category (1). Either the number or the string (M, L etc.) changing would be a difference. There may be just a digit or a string in that column. So any difference at all per ID  would count.

Comment: I posted a solution.  Hope it helps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can group by 'ID', 'Category' and `filter` the groups having number of distinct 'Score' greater than 1

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    group_by(ID, Category) %>% 
    filter(n_distinct(Score) > 1)
# A tibble: 4 x 4
# Groups:   ID, Category [2]
#     ID Name  Score Category
#  <int> <chr> <chr>    <int>
#1   100 AA    1: M         1
#2   100 BB    2: M         1
#3   300 EE    4: L         1
#4   300 FF    <NA>         1
```

Or for the second case

```
df1 %>%
    group_by(ID) %>%
    filter(n_distinct(Category) > 1 & n_distinct(Score) > 1)
# A tibble: 2 x 4
# Groups:   ID [1]
#    ID Name  Score Category
#  <int> <chr> <chr>    <int>
#1   200 CC    3: M         1
#2   200 DD    2: M         2
```

---

It can be done in a single call with `map2`

```
library(purrr)
map2(list(c("ID", "Category"), "ID"),
     list("Score", c("Category", "Score")),
      ~ df1 %>%
           group_by_at(.x) %>%
            filter_at(vars(.y), all_vars(n_distinct(.) > 1)))
#[[1]]
# A tibble: 4 x 4
# Groups:   ID, Category [2]
#     ID Name  Score Category
#  <int> <chr> <chr>    <int>
#1   100 AA    1: M         1
#2   100 BB    2: M         1
#3   300 EE    4: L         1
#4   300 FF    <NA>         1

#[[2]]
# A tibble: 2 x 4
# Groups:   ID [1]
#     ID Name  Score Category
#  <int> <chr> <chr>    <int>
#1   200 CC    3: M         1
#2   200 DD    2: M         2
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = c(100L, 100L, 200L, 200L, 300L, 300L, 400L, 
400L), Name = c("AA", "BB", "CC", "DD", "EE", "FF", "GG", "HH"
), Score = c("1: M", "2: M", "3: M", "2: M", "4: L", NA, "1: M", 
"1: M"), Category = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L)), 
 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a base R solution,

```
i1 <- !!with(df, ave(Category, ID, FUN = function(i) length(unique(i)) != 1))
i2 <- with(df, ave(Score, ID, FUN = function(i) length(unique(i)) != 1)) == 'TRUE'

#data frame 1
df[i1,]
#   ID Name Score Category
#3 200   CC   3_M        1
#4 200   DD   2_M        2

#Data frame 2

df[i1+i2 == 1,]
#   ID Name Score Category
#1 100   AA   1_M        1
#2 100   BB   2_M        1
#5 300   EE   4_L        1
#6 300   FF  <NA>        1
```